# Call method in an activity from another class that extends Application

Tags: java, android

Hi I am trying to call this method in MainActivity from another class called Startup that extends Application so that it could load each time the app starts:

Can someone show me how to do this? I have read lots of answers but I have not seen any questions that has a class that extends Application yet, I think that caused the issue. All answers that I have seen are about how to call a method from another class that extends Activity :/

this is the method in mainActivity:

```
 public void showPinLayout() {

        //if initialize in oncreate will cause nullpointer error
        indicatorDots = (IndicatorDots) findViewById(R.id.indicator_dotsMain);
        pinLockView = (PinLockView) findViewById(R.id.pinlockviewMain);
        pinLockView.attachIndicatorDots(indicatorDots);
...
}
```

this is the Startup class that extends Application and has been initialized in manifest:

```
<application
        android:name=".Startup" ...>
```

```
public class Startup extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Startup", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
        mainActivity.showPinLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: User the view as a static variable and do as you want

Comment: Look here for answer: this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47766894/calling-a-method-from-another-class-is-causing-app-to-crash/47772559#47772559

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing something like let the **MainActivity** start, and in **onCreate** of the **MainActivity** call the method in **Startup** class to initialize some method. the reason is that you don't know at what time the activity will be initialized so wait for it then on **Lifecycle** Callback initialize some method if needed.

For ex.

```
public class Startup extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Startup", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       
    }

    public void initMain(Context context){
      ((MainActivity)context).showPinLayout();
    }

}
```

and in MainActivity do something like this.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //just before showing the UI, call the application class method to initialize some method if needed
    ((Startup)getApplicationContext()).initMain(this);
}
```

Comment: Hi, there is an error when I tried to call the initMain() when I called it in MainActivity : "Expected 1 arguments but found 0"

Comment: changed the method you need to pass this to initMain(this) @Lionlollipop

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot `new` an activity and you should not hold a static reference to an activity to call this method on (since it can lead to leaks), the proper way to access an activity method through app class is through `BroadcastReceiver`. Here is a simple example:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String ACTION_SHOW_PIN_LAYOUT = "com.example.package.SHOW_PIN_LAYOUT";

    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            showPinLayout();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate();
        ...
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_SHOW_PIN_LAYOUT));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        ...
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
}
```

**Startup.java**

```
public class Startup extends Application {

    ...

    public void callShowPinLayout() {
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(MainActivity.ACTION_SHOW_PIN_LAYOUT));
    }
}
```

Note that for this to work, MainActivity must be created first, so call `callShowPinLayout` in a resonable time when you have ensured of your activity creation.

Also I'd suggest [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) library which is created to ease out these kind of stuff.

### Edit:

Since you intend to show a pin lock when user starts the app, you should only deal with activities. I would recommend implementing something like the following: Declaring your pin lock layout as an independent activity. Creating a startup activity (could be a splash screen) and marking it as the launcher activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` to decide whether to show the pin lock or main activity.

**StartupActivity.java**

```
public class StartupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_startup);

        boolean shouldShowLockScreen = true;  // you can replace this with your own lock screen visibility algorithm
        if (shouldShowLockScreen) {
            // Open LockScreenActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LockScreenActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            // Open MainActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        finish();
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.java**

```
<application
    ...>
    <activity
        android:name=".StartupActivity"
        android:theme="@style/StartupTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        ...
    </activity>
</application>
```

With this implementation whenever user enters the app with a cold start, the lock screen algorithm determines if he/she should enter `MainActivity` or not and if a hot start happens you can easily start your mighty `StatupActivity` if needed to in `onResume()` of your `MainActivity`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, how to callshowPinLayout? Is it called in the startup class or in MainActivity oncreate() method?

Comment: I called the callshowPinLayout method in the oncreate() of Startup class to ensure it is called after the oncreate of MainActivity loads with a Handler(delay a few seconds), is this the right way to do?

Comment: When you start the app for the first time (cold start) the application class gets created and then the calling activity is created and displayed after a short sequence of time (which may be different on various devices). In a hot start situation the app class was already created and only activities get prepared, and warm start sometimes is a combination of these tow situations. So I would say there is no guaranty that the app class creation leads to activity creation. You can read more about startup patterns [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time).

Comment: Note that you **can** access you application class through you activity but not vice versa. What is your intention to call this exactly?

Comment: The intention to call this is to show a pin lock layout every time when user enter this app, I tried the sharedpreference method before but it doesn't work :(