# Android How to set button click actions from 2nd activity layout

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android and Java, so I'm having problems with on click method. Here's i have 2 activities main and sub having different layouts.
I want to know is there any method to implement on click action on button view which is not from main activity layout
I can able show button view of sub activity layout but its on click action does not works.

Answer (score 0):

What I normally like to do is set the onClickListener programmatically

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(v -> handleMyButtonClick());
```

Since you are new to Java you may not be familiar with lambdas. So your code could also look more like is.

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // do something when the button is clicked
      // maybe call handleMyButtonClick();
    }
};
```

The onClickListener has to be set after the button has been initialized but before you actually click it.

Comment: Thanks for respond, I have a custom volume seekbar not button , Basically i need a code in which my seekbar works from any activity layout i have declared (xml layout) regardless of declaring repeatedly in all the activities.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create object of your Activity, By using this Object you are able to use activity method.

For more detail; visit this link. [How to use method from another Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47766894/calling-a-method-from-another-class-is-causing-app-to-crash/47772559#47772559)

Use this to call your Button's OnClick Action.

Comment: Hi, i do not want to initialize the button in second activity class. Is thier any way that in second layout ,buttons itself find its activity class where they belongs. Or can i create custom buttons ,like found in  some xml layout like <com.xx.mybutton  />