# how i can to call method from another actitvity to this activity android studio mvvm

Tags: android

i need to get insert method which is exist in warehouse activity to another activity
**to insert object of warehouse entity** i do'nt try to open WareHouseActivity just call insert method from activity in my activity to pass object of it

*i use this two method but the problem doesn't solve i know why this methods are uncorrect but i put them for example*

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_daily_movement); 

WareHouseentity warehouseentity=new WareHouseentity();

method 1 ;;;;;;;;;;;;;
((WarehouseActivity)getApplicationContext).insert(warehouseentity);

method 2;;;;;;;;;;
WareHouseActivity warehouseactivity=new WareHouseActivity();
warehouseactivity.insert(warehouseentity)
```

}

Comment: This is a wrong approach . `insert` method hold business logic so it should be separated  from the UI layer . Create a separate class to handle all Crud actions then u can just call the method of that class from anywhere by creating Object or by using Singleton Object  . these things are way too easy if You follow some pattern like `MVVM` ..

Comment: @ADM can you tell me how to make it please i try but cannot get method because context of activity which i try get insert method from it

Answer (score 1):

You need to create object of your Activity, By using this Object you are able to use activity method.

For more detail; visit this link. [How to use method from another Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47766894/calling-a-method-from-another-class-is-causing-app-to-crash/47772559#47772559)

Use this to call your `insert` action.

Comment: That's totally wrong you don't create an Object of `Activity` never .. And passing a static instance around is also a big No no .. This can cause several problem like Memory leak and lifecycle related crashes ..

Comment: @ADM ,  agree with this. Can you please guide us to achieve this with a right way!?