# How to change the text of text view on fragment B, when I click on different views in fragment A accordingly in kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent, android-safe-args

I have Two Fragments, for example - FragmentA and FragmentB

In FragmentA I have multiple ImageButtons,
In FragmentB I have a TextView

What I want to do is, when I click on any ImageButton in FragmentA then I want to assign a particular text to TextView in FragmentB.

For Example:-

If I click on Image Button 1 in the FragmentA then the text in FragmentB should be "Hello Jane"

If I click on Image Button 2 in the FragmentA then the text in FragmentB should be "Hello Foster"

and so on...

How to do this in Kotlin.
Please Help me.

Comment: check if it can help you -https://stackoverflow.com/a/47772559/6534707

Answer (score 0):

One way of how you can achieve this is to a have a common bundle, whenever you detect the click on those views you need to update the bundle accordingly and update it to the latest click. when you navigate to the second fragment you will get the most recent bundle `.putExtra()`.Using the same key will update the value. so you will get the needed text and set it to your textfield.
**Note**: *you dont have to navigate immediately after creating the bundle. You may or maynot opt to do it immediately or at a latter time*.

Comment: This will only work if the user navigates to the fragment A when the button is clicked.

Comment: Yes that is what he asked. Do you want it to be done in the background?. Then you need to implement a viewmodel for that activity that hosted the two fragments and store data into the viewmodel then take it from viewmodel from other fragment. An advice "your other fragment which is in background or not started will be in the frozen state".

Comment: Im not the author of the question.

Comment: Ok. but why did you raise that comment? is it for clarity or you wanted to ask any question?

Comment: sorry maybe I sounded a bit rude, wasn't my intention :D

Comment: nah, I understood your question i updated my solution so you will have better clarity.